# Windows 7 Virtual WiFi using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-7, virtual, wireless, wifi

Windows 7 introduced Virtual WiFi which allows you to create **hotspots**. However I can't find any tutorials on doing it in C#. I found **Virtual Router** (It is open source and is written in C#) but I can't seem to figure out how it works because it has a lot of unrelated code since it is implemented as a service.

*Can anyone explain how can I create a hotspot and assign IP addresses to clients? I don't need features like ICS but I want to be able to **broadcast gateway and DNS** information.*

*There is also a closed source alternative called Connectify. I did manage to get its source but it didn't help much. It uses an open source library but I don't know how to create hotspots with it.*

Comment: Why not just install Virtual Router (MSI) ?

Comment: Because I need to modify few aspects of it + I need something running as an app not as a service

Comment: How did you get the source of Connectify?

Comment: It is a .NET application , god's sake. Use your common sense.

Comment: There's no need for that attitude on here; Nate's asking a reasonable question. @Nate: you can use applications like .NET Reflector to reverse-engineer .NET code from the binary files.  It's not the original source, but it's plenty understandable unless the app has been obfuscated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about looking into this Code-Plex project [Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've found a project that does exactly what you want, why not work on understanding that project?

It looks like most of the code you're interested in is in the "VirtualRouter.Wlan" project.  Start there and try asking specific questions if you don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using System.Diagnostics;
        using System.Security.Principal;

        namespace WifiRouter
        {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                bool connect = false;
                public Form1()
                {

                    InitializeComponent();
                }

                public static bool IsAdmin()
                {
                    WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                    WindowsPrincipal p = new WindowsPrincipal(id);
                    return p.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
                }
                public void RestartElevated()
                {
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                    startInfo.FileName = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
                    startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                    try
                    {
                        Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }

                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
                }
                private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    string ssid = textBox1.Text, key = textBox2.Text;
                    if (!connect)
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("SSID cannot be left blank !",
                            "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            if (textBox2.Text == null || textBox2.Text == "")
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Key value cannot be left blank !",
                                "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (key.Length >= 6)
                                {
                                    Hotspot(ssid, key, true);
                                    textBox1.Enabled = false;
                                    textBox2.Enabled = false;
                                    button1.Text = "Stop";
                                    connect = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Key should be more then or Equal to 6 Characters !",
                                    "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Hotspot(null, null, false);
                        textBox1.Enabled = true;
                        textBox2.Enabled = true;
                        button1.Text = "Start";
                        connect = false;
                    }
                }
                private void Hotspot(string ssid, string key,bool status)
                {
                    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
                    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

                    if (process != null)
                    {
                        if (status)
                        {
                            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=" + ssid + " key=" + key);
                            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan start hosted network");
                            process.StandardInput.Close();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh wlan stop hostednetwork");
                            process.StandardInput.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (!IsAdmin())
                    {
                        RestartElevated();
                    }
                }

                private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
                {
                    Hotspot(null, null, false);
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }
        }
```